# how to load a hex file into a microcontroller using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that does a few things... having trouble with it.
I can't find any examples to help me, but what I need is...

1. run 3rd party program to create 1 .hex file
2. load that and 2 other .hex files into a microcontroller

Comment: There are lots of different microcontrollers with lots of different methods for loading .hex files onto them. Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: More so what I'm looking for is a decent list of commands with examples on how to use them for .bat. I know there is a "LOAD" command, but I can't find syntax like, "LOAD xxx1.hex into Y location. Also: I found the "run this program" syntax, but can't figure out how to tell that program what to do in that .bat file. Or do I even need to worry about that part. That program (1) only creates a .hex with device info. Thanks, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

in windows 2000 and above, you cannot do this. due to the limitations of batch.

in DOS you would be able to, with the `APPEND` command, but it doesn't exist in new operating systems.

Bill Gates just took it out.

Comment: This might be a valid comment (if you had sufficient reputation to have that privilege). It's not an answer to the question. (And I doubt very much that "Bill Gates just took it out", as I don't think his fingers typed any of the released code for Windows in the past few decades.)

Comment: i know that this is supposed to be a comment.

Comment: and **Bill Gates just took it out** was just a metaphor

Comment: Heh, for sure! I'm confused though. If this isn't possible to run in .bat, why would my team request I do it? I'm not sure how to automate this, but essentially it's just a 1 button application. Click here and hit enter to make that 3rd party program create a unique ID in a .hex file, then load that and 2 others into the microcontrollers. After that, display pass/fail and goto start.

Comment: you wont be able to do this without using some other type of coding. like vbscript.

Comment: Using "answers" to get by not having enough privileges to comment is a violation of guidelines here. If you want the ability to comment, work to earn that ability. Do not use the answer space for anything except just what it's supposed to be - an actual answer to the question. If you need more info on privileges and how to earn them, see the [help] and [about] pages.